# Printing the matrix square shape from scanner input in java

Tags: java

currently, I'm doing an assignment about the matrix determinant calculator, I'm creating a matrix 2x2, I'm done with the taking value from the user part, but I don't know how can we use that value to do more calculation as well as printing the square shape like this:

```
| 1 1|
| 1 1|
```

Can you guys help me out with this, this is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Matrix Determinant Calculator!");
        System.out.println("Would you like to calculate the determinant of a new matrix?");
        System.out.println("1. Yes"+ "  "+ "2. No");
        System.out.print("Option: ");
        int i, j;
        int option = input.nextInt();
        if(option == 1){
            System.out.println("What is the dimension of the matrix?");
            System.out.println("1. 2x2 "+ "  "+"2. 3x3");
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            if(choice == 1){ //matrix 2x2
                    int [][] input2x2 = new int[2][2];
                    System.out.println("Great! Let's calculate this determinant then.");
                    System.out.println("Please insert all the values for your matrix. Direction: [row][column]: your value\n");
                
                    for(i = 1; i<= 2;i++){
                        for( j = 1; j <= 2; j++){
                            System.out.print("New matrix: ["+i +"]"+ "["+ j+"]: ");
                            int matrix2x2 = input.nextInt();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the formula for calculating the determinant of a 2x2 matrix, like `{{a, b}, {c, d}}`, is `ad - bc`. So after getting the matrix you can easily calculate it with a method like the following:

```
public static int determinant(int[][] matrix2x2){
    return matrix2x2[0][0]*matrix2x2[1][1]  -
                  matrix2x2[0][1]*matrix2x2[0][1];
}
```

Now put this code after `for` loops:

```
for(i = 0; i< 2;i++){
    for( j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        System.out.print("New matrix: ["+i +"]"+ "["+ j+"]: ");
        input2x2[i][j]=input.nextInt();
    }
}
System.out.println("The determinant is : "+determinant(input2x2);
```

Note that `i` and `j` should start from 0 so you don't get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You're hard coding the 2x2 and the 3x3 indices. Don't use if statements. The printing of 2x2 and the 3x3 indices should be coded in a single nested for loop.

this is a similar question and should be of interest to you. [creating a matrix in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939957/creating-a-matrix-in-java/36939999)

Answer (score 0):

> You Messed Up The Code Buddy So I Rewrote it :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j;
        System.out.println("Enter the size of matrix you want : ");
        System.out.print("X : ");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Y : ");
        int y = input.nextInt();
        int[][] mat=new int [x][y];
        for (i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){
            for (j = 0 ; j < y ; j++){
                System.out.print("Position X:["+i+"] Y:["+j+"]");
                mat[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){
            for (j = 0 ; j < x ; j++){
                System.out.print(mat[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

> EDIT : Why do only 2x2 and 3x3 matrix why limiting :)

Comment: haha, because the assignment limit to only 2x2 and 3x3, btw, this is really helpful, thanks a lot